# update vachar column to date in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Trying to update a column with `varchar` datatype e.g. '1950-08-14' to a `date` datatype using

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = to_date(columnname, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname TYPE DATE USING to_date(columnname, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

but both return the error message

```
ERROR:  invalid value "columnname" for "YYYY"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.
```

Referencing http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: You sure you're not quoting the column name? Could you show the actual query you're running?

Comment: for the first instance of 'columnname' I've tried using the same column i.e. the one being changed to_date() and also a new empty columnname of type 'date'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
    ALTER COLUMN columnname TYPE DATE USING to_date(columnname, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

is correct.

The error message means that you have invalid value in column `columnname` (actualy the invalid value is 'columnname').
All the values in the column must have the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', e.g. '2015-01-01' (or be null).

---

Solution with a new column.

Create a function to convert `varchar` to `date` which returns `null` for invalid values:

```
create or replace function varchar_to_date_or_null(str varchar)
returns date language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return to_date(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
exception
    when invalid_datetime_format then return null;
end $$;
```

Add a new column and update it using the function:

```
alter table tablename add new_column date;

update tablename
set new_column = varchar_to_date_or_null(columnname);
```

Comment: any idea how I can bypass this? I have a table of 45,000 rows with a column of dates in text data type. The one's I've looked at all seem to follow the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'... perhaps some are missing for incorrectly input? should I remove strings that don't fit that format first?

Comment: Nice, thanks!  Conveniently I've been trying to get better at working with 'create or replace function' as well.