# PostgreSQL, change data type from text to date

Tags: postgresql, ddl, sqldatatypes

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains a column of data type 'text', that column contains only dates.

I'm trying to convert it to date type, But it doesn't work.

```
publication_date
-----------
"9/16/2006"
"9/1/2004"
"11/1/2003"
"5/1/2004"
"9/13/2004"
"4/26/2005"
"9/12/2005"
"11/1/2005"
"4/30/2002"
"8/3/2004"
```

```
ALTER TABLE books 
ALTER COLUMN publication_date SET DATA TYPE date;
```

outputs:

```
ERROR:  column "publication_date" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING publication_date::date".
SQL state: 42804
```

Answer (score 7):

The error message tells you what to do:

```
ALTER TABLE books 
ALTER COLUMN publication_date SET DATA TYPE date
      USING to_date(publication_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: This raises another error: 
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "11/31/2000"
SQL state: 22008

Comment: @yovelcohen: then obviously you have invalid date values in your column. See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791975